# htmlFor not working

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, label

I created 3 `radio` buttons and a `label` for each of them using JavaScript. When I try adding `for` in the label using `htmlFor`, it doesn't apply it to the actual DOM Element. Meaning, when I try using the `label` on the webpage, it doesn't select the `radio` button.

I checked in the developer tools, and saw that the `labels` did not have `for` applied to them.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var _doc = document,
  sliderWrapper = _doc.getElementById('sliderWrapper'),
  radioWrapper = _doc.createElement('div');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var radio = _doc.createElement('input');
  var niceRadio = _doc.createElement('lable');
  var index = radioWrapper.children.length / 2;

  niceRadio.className = 'niceRadio';
  niceRadio.htmlFor = radio.id = 'sliderRadio' + index;
  radio.type = 'radio';
  radio.name = 'myName';

  radioWrapper.appendChild(radio);
  radioWrapper.appendChild(niceRadio);
  console.log(niceRadio.htmlFor);
}

sliderWrapper.appendChild(radioWrapper);
```

```css
.niceRadio {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
.niceRadio:hover {
  border-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderWrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: Fixing a simple typo solves the problem. This question should probably be closed for that reason because it's root cause isn't programming related.

Comment: Spell correct label element first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `htmlFor` is used to bind a label to a specific form element. However, it uses the `id` of that form element (not the `name`).

Source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement/htmlFor):

> The HTMLLabelElement.htmlFor property reflects the value of the for
>   content property. That means that this script-accessible property is
>   used to set and read the value of the content property for, **which is
>   the ID** of the label's associated control element.

Also, in your fiddle, you misspelled `label`.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h09mm827/2/

Comment: Oh. I think the only problem was that I misspelled `label`.

Comment: Be aware, though, that you are using the `for` attribute incorrectly. It is meant to use the id of the element to bind to. I'm sure using the `name` will work but I don't know the consequences if you do that.